# How to use kubernetes replication controllers to replicate message-based services

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes, microservices

We usually use message passing to send messages to decoupled services. This makes service discovery a non-issue, because (with AMQP in RabbitMQ for instance) you can use the broker's routing capability to dispatch messages to the right queues that feed the correct services. Load balancing is also handled by the message broker.

Enter kubernetes.

The use case that is usually laid out when talking about service replication and re-spawning failing services, is when your clients use some active protocol like http to contact a service, even if this service handles requests asynchronously. In this context, it is a natural fit to have replication controllers, that manage a group of services and a single entry point to load balance between them.

I like kubernetes' intuitive concepts, like rolling deployments, but how to you control this beasts that don't have an http interface ?

**UPDATE:**
I am not trying to set up a cluster of message brokers. I am looking at message consumers as services. Service clients don't connect directly to the services, they send messages to the message broker. The message broker acts as a load balancer in a way, and dispatches the messages to the subscribed queue consumers. These consumers implement the service.

My question gravitates around the fact that most usage patterns in demos handle services that are called via http, and kubernetes does a good job here to create a service proxy for these services, and a replication controller. Is it possible to create replication controllers for my kind of service, which does not have a http interface per se, and have all the benefits of rolling updates, and minimum instances?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question. Are you asking how to use RabbitMQ with Kubernetes? Or how to set up a RabbitMQ cluster: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html? Or how rolling updates interact with RabbitMQ? Or something else?

I think you should be able to create one service and one replication controller per server, and then use the service DNS names in the cluster configuration file. This is the current approach used to run Zookeeper, also. We have a long-standing TODO to make this less verbose (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/260), but the current approach should be straightforward. You do lose the ability to use a single kubectl rolling-update command to update the cluster, but it's also straightforward to update the instances individually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have added a section to my question, to clarify the scope.

Comment: tl:dr...that is a long discussion but what is the "current approach"?